# Is it possible to get to the method definition in visual studio code for AngularJS project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-code

I want to find the method definition in my AngularJS project but I am not able to find any shortcut to this. I've tried `Ctrl + Click` but it did take me to the first occurrence of the variable where it was defined in that particular file not to the method definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Go to Definition

If a language supports it, you can go to the definition of a symbol by pressing F12.

If you press Ctrl and hover over a symbol, a preview of the declaration will appear:

[image]

Tip: You can jump to the definition with Ctrl+Click or open the definition to the side with Ctrl+Alt+Click.

Read the full documentation here. [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved)

Comment: Then I guess AngularJS does not provide go to definition !